# Iterating over all pivot table objects

Tags: excel, vba

Currently have a list of hundreds of pivot table measures:

[image]

How can I iterate over all the objects possible in VBA?

For example, pulling [Salesperson], then [Product], then [Region], etc

(I know it will be a For Each loop on a PivotTable command...)

Comment: Have you tried using Record Macro?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PivotTable1 is the name of your pivot table

```
For Each objPivotField In Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields
    Debug.Print objPivotField.Name
Next
```

Will enable you to traverse all pivot fields

[image]

Comment: What this does is simply pull what is loaded in the pivottable. What I need is all the selections possible. For example, if you had not selected [Product] above, but need to pull it.

Comment: No. This will print ALL columns which are part of the pivot table irrespective of their selection status. Check image in the answer - I did not select `place` and still it was printed in the debug window

Comment: Perhaps a better question is, if the item has not been selected, how can I pull a list of any and all items that are possible to be selected?

Comment: **From your image added update** I see, however it appears I am only getting what is selected. Is there a special setting that you have selected?

Comment: Nop ..its simple pivot with all default settings

Comment: My pivot table sources from an Azure Analysis Services Tabular model

Comment: Can you check on a blank workbook with a small pivot to see if my code works on that. If that works then it would mean that your pivot got some special condition/settings

Comment: Yes, your code works when I built out a small PivotTable. The question now become, how to pull all the fields, if we can view them in the item selection, we should be able to pull each one